# PIC 16F877A interrupt handling

Tags: pic, uart, interrupts

I am trying to write a simple code to receive and resend data using USART but the code is not working.

Could someone give suggestions on possible flaws in the code?

I am using USART at baud rate 9600 with clock frequency 4MHz.

```
#include<pic.h>
void main()
{   
    TRISB=0X00;
    TXEN=1;
    SYNC=0;
    BRGH=1;
    SPEN=1;
    CREN=1;
   //RCEN=1;
    SPBRG=0X19;
    INTCON=0X80;
    TRISC7=1;
    TRISC6=0;
    RCIE=1;
    TXIE=1;
    while(1);
}

void interrupt rectrans()
{
    if(RCIF==1)
    {
      TXREG=RCREG;
      while(!TRMT);
      RCIF=0;
    }
    else if(TXIF==1)
    {
      TXIF=0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is not working? And what compiler are you using? Are you sure the interrupt gets called? To check, you could temporarily use an unused pin as debug signal and attach an LED to it. Then, in the beginning of `main` you turn it off and in the interrupt you turn it on. Are you even sure that the PIC is working, executing the program, etc.? (same way to check)

Comment: @CamilStaps , thanks for attending my question. I simulated the setup using isis but could not see any changes in the RCREG register(ISIS>>watch window).I am using XC8 compiler.Regarding the interrupts, I could not see any changes in the PIR1 register. I am a beginner when it comes to PIC and interrupts. so probably I have done some mistake at the concept level.

Comment: You haven't enabled Peripheral Interrupts in your INTCON register (bit 6). Try setting INTCON to 0xC0 instead of 0x80.

Comment: Thank you very much @CamilStaps. I understood my mistake.Its working perfectly now.

Comment: Thank you very much @brhans. I understood my mistake. The issue has been resolved.

Comment: @CamilStaps , I solved it using brahans help. I will surely update my account as I learn more on these topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't enabled Peripheral Interrupts in your INTCON register (bit 6).
Try setting INTCON to 0xC0 instead of 0x80.